# Dimension of some moduli spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I expect that this is a very easy question, but somehow I can't get it.  What is the dimension of the moduli space of complete intersections of degree 2 and 4 in $\mathbb{P}^5$?  The answer should be 89.

I apologize again that if the question is too easy.

Comment: Where do you get 89 from? I seem to get 91.

Comment: This paper:
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506196
page 12

How are you getting 91?  Seems pretty close :)

Comment: Dear user148177, I am not inclined to doubt those authors. So let me think a bit more about whether I messed up somewhere.

Comment: May I ask what approach you took to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I arrived at my answer.

First, choose a quadric in $\mathbf P^5$. The parameter space for such choices has dimension ${5+2 \choose 2} -1$ = 20.

Next, choose a quartic in $\mathbf P^5$, *modulo* the already chosen quadric. (Two quartics forms which differ by a multiple of the chosen quadric will give the same complete intersection.) The parameter space for such choices has dimension $ \left( {5+4 \choose 4} - {5+2\choose 2} \right) -1$ = 126-21-1=104.

OK, so the parameter space of complete intersections has dimension 104+20=124. But now we want the moduli space, so we divide out by the action of $PGL(6)$. That has dimension $6^2-1=35$. So in the end we get a space of dimension $124-35=89$.

Comment: Looks great, thanks!

Comment: Dear @user148177, you're welcome! I am glad I was able to find those extra (-1)'s...